# How to add prefix or suffix to post_tag slug?

Tags: tags

I want to add prefix or suffix to all `post_tag` slugs.

For example one tag URL: `example.com/tag/post-tag-slug`
all such URLs should be suffixed with a suffix: `example.com/tag/post-tag-slug-suffix`.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by following code:

```
function custom_tag_rewrite()
{
 add_rewrite_rule("^tag/(.+)-suffix/?$", 'index.php?post_type=post&tag=$matches[1]', 'top');
 flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'custom_tag_rewrite');
```

and try open like this http://example.com/tag/post-tag-slug-suffix

Comment: Dear sir, with the code you was provided, am able to access  tag from example.com/tag/post-tag-slug-suffix but i want to add suffix to tag slug while we add a new tag without using rewrite.